# How to fill an Array conditionally?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JS code:

```
let a = false
let b = true
let c = [...(a ? {d: 1} : {})]
```

I'm trying to set `c` to `[{d: 1}]` if `a` is true, and set it to `[]` if `a` is false. It's throwing the error `object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Why is it throwing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the expressions in arrays.

```js
const
    a = false,
    b = true,
    c = [...(a ? [{ d: 1 }] : [])],
    d = [...(b ? [{ d: 1 }] : [])];

console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: That's it, thanks!